# Best approach foreach inside form

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm having a one to many relationship. Lets say it is `one user may have one or more fruits`. Let's say the user has 3 products.

- Apple
- Banana
- Grape

I want the user to make a log of the products. Lets say the form looks something like this:

```
<label for="description">Give a description of the log</label>
<input type="text" name="description" id="description"/>

@forelse($user->fruits as $fruit)
    <label for="{{$fruit->name}}">give condition of all {{$fruit->name}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="{{$fruit->name}}" name="{{$fruit->name}}" />
@empty
    No fruits available!
@endforelse

<button type="submit">
```

This would give me a form where I can describe the log that will be saved and also do a status update on the user's apples, bananas and grapes.

Keep in mind this is just an example. I feel like this will be difficult to handle in the controller (how would I get the right `$_POST` values?), processingpower-inefficient and that it sort of works against the principles of MVC. 
Is there a better approach to use all the `one to many` values and use them all in the same form using html/php without it getting messy to work with? I'm using Laravel but this might be an over-all question for all frameworks.

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm not really concerned about the speed since I'm running this on quite a decent server. I'm just not feeling like this would be the most logic approach, I feel like there should be a better way instead of foreaching in the form, then try to get the POST values in the controller back and apply code to them individually. The way I showed it might be the only way, it might not be the only way and I'm looking for the best way (and that might be this one, then I'm glad to hear it is).

Comment: Are you using Laravel eloquent models?  I would have thought the fillable attribute could deal with that quite nicely in the controller.  What does the form input / $response look like?

Comment: @brianlmerritt I am indeed using eloquent models. Problem is that every user is able to add their own kinds of fruit, so the fillable attribute won't work here since someone might also add pineapple or whatever if he wants to. Mass assignment wouldn't work here unfortunately..

Comment: I spent serious time today with collections (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections) and managed to cut 50 line nested for each loops down to just a few groupBy and keyBy and filter and map calls - 8 lines of code in the end.  Can you draw a simple table or map of the relations?

Comment: ps - fillable just decides the field names, not the values that go into them.  Have a look at pivot tables, which are sort of equivalent of WordPress meta tables

Comment: Great painting, but you haven't set out how you want to store the user input.  For example, with a tagging system a simple pivot table would do (a pivot table would be an added table with just two fields - $user->id, $fruit->id).  If you want serious multi-way relationships ($user => $fruit, $user => $mobilePhones, $fruit => $mobilePhones look at polymorphic https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Final comment (otherwise we have to go to chat). Please do show your Models so we come up with a sensible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach an array to the form, like 
    `input name='fruit[]'`
And PHP will parse every fruit element into a easy to use array for you